# Annotate generic base class

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm creating the base repository class and getting the following error:

```
from typing import Any, Generic, Type, TypeVar

from sqlmodel import Session, SQLModel, select

from app.models.base import BaseModel
from app.models.notification import Notification
from app.types import SQLModelType

T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseModel)

class BaseCRUD(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, db: Session, model: Type[BaseModel]) -> None:
        self.db = db
        self.model = model

    def create(self, item: T) -> T:
        self.db.add(item)
        self.db.commit()
        self.db.refresh(item)

        return item

    def get(self, uuid: Any) -> T:
        statement = select(self.model).where(self.model.uuid == uuid)

        return self.db.exec(statement).one() <---- Error: Mypy: Incompatible return value type (got "BaseModel", expected "T")
```

How do I annotate so that mypy knows that it is an object of a subclass of BaseModel? The `TypeVar` and `bound` are made for that right? Is it a bug then?

Comment: It's right in the error message -- you're returning a regular old `BaseModel`, as opposed to the specific `BaseModel` subclass (`T`) from the type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Figured it out.
I should use `T` to annotate a `self.model` like so:

```
class BaseCRUD(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, db: Session, model: Type[T]) -> None:  # <--- T instead of BaseModel
        self.db = db
        self.model = model
```